# dplyr works using funs, but gives error with list

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the Pearson's correlation for each group in a data.table. The code works using fun(cor(., true_beta)), but gives error if I use:
 list(cor(., true_beta)).

I am also trying to put 2 functions in the list like:
 list(cor(., true_beta, method = 'pearson'), cor(., true_beta, method = 'kendall'))

I have tried list(cor(as.numeric(.), true, )) but it still gives error:

(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

the code works:

```
plot.data.corr = plot.data.info %>%
            select(-c('predictors')) %>%
            group_by(method, boot) %>%
            summarise_at(c("coefs"), funs(kendall.tau = cor(., true_beta, method = 'kendall'))) %>%
            left_join(plot.data.corr, by = c('method', 'boot'))
```

but it does not work:

```
plot.data.corr = plot.data.info %>%
        select(-c('predictors')) %>%
        group_by(method, boot) %>%
        summarise_at(c("coefs"), list(kendall.tau = cor(., true_beta, method = 'kendall'))) %>%
        left_join(plot.data.corr, by = c('method', 'boot'))
```

it give error:

Error in cor(., true_beta, method = "kendall") : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Place a tilde before `cor` e.g. `iris%>%group_by(Species)%>%summarise_at(c("Petal.Length"),  list(pr=~cor(., Petal.Width, method = 'pearson'), ken=~cor(., Petal.Width, method = 'kendall')))`

Comment: `funs` is obsolete, and `list` uses a tilde as mentioned above.

Comment: @A.Suliman That could be posted as the answer.